# Do mathematic operation according to symbol in element.innerText

Tags: javascript, calculator

I am preparing calculator and I would like to have only one function, to get the result according to input value

```
const equals=document.getElementById("equals");
equals.addEventListener('click',()=>getResult(a));
a= symbol.innerText
```

```
function getResult(a){
result.innerText = +calculations1.innerText a +calculations2.innerText;
> }
```

Where **a** could be either +, -, %, /, *.

Do you think it is possible to do this if **a** is stored as a string in element.innerText to do one function depending what stays there?

I try to make my function cleaner

Comment: create function for each operator then create `switch`  function to switch between them.

Comment: you could use `eval` but that's a bad idea. also taking the `innerText` to decide on action is a bad design idea.